# iOS - Ensure execution on main thread

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, multitasking, shared-resource

I want to know how to call my `function` on the *main thread*.

How do I make sure my `function` is called on the *main thread*?

*(this follows a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054457/ios-concurrent-access-to-memory-resources) of mine).*

Comment: I would imagine only classes that call your delegate methods using `[NSObject performSelectorOnMainThread]` can be considered *safe*.  Otherwise if the object just calls `[NSObject performSelector]` your delegate methods are running in the context of the caller's thread.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> there any rule I can follow to be sure that my app executes my own code just in the main thread?

Typically you wouldn't need to do anything to ensure this — your list of things is usually enough. Unless you're interacting with some API that happens to spawn a thread and run your code in the background, you'll be running on the main thread.

If you want to be really sure, you can do things like

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:anObj waitUntilDone:YES];
```

to execute a method on the main thread. (There's a GCD equivalent too.)

Comment: How would you go about the case where you spawn a thread to run code in the background?

Answer (score 168):

This will do it:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {

   //Your code goes in here
   NSLog(@"Main Thread Code");

}];
```

Comment: It does, thanks. Do you know if this is subject to the same kind of restrictions as meccans' answer (which is the GCD version I guess), say 'don't call this from the main thread'?

Comment: Well I just find this way easier because if you do it this way you don't have to make a new method every time you want to do something on the main thread.

Comment: This helped me with a socket programming mysterious hang when upgrading my XCode to the latest iOS 6.1 simulator. The code was writing to a socket immediately after reading some data from it. For some strange reason, that worked like a charm in iOS 5.1 simulator, but not in 6.0 or 6.1 - using this suggestion to execute the write operation on the socket in the main thread solved my problem, and it works in all simulator versions and devices!

Comment: So I was using the code block in the above answer: (dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  //Your code goes in here
  NSLog(@"Main Thread Code");       
});) since gcd is known to work well however, I ran into an issue where the main thread wouldn't take priority and the app would stall in one of the iPod5's I have. I switched to using the NSOperationQueue instead and it worked fine. Weird odd case but I thought, I'd document it here.

Comment: So this, unlike dispatch_get_main_queue, you can do directly on the main thread?

Comment: This is better as I can "throw" whatever code inside without having to "design" a function for a performselector. Also, whatever that's executed from within there goes on the main thread as well. Thanks!

Comment: Although I prefer this option (looks nicer) it is slow with hard UI (e.g. progress updates lag).  For that you should use dispatch_async.

Answer (score 139):

**When you're using iOS >= 4**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  //Your main thread code goes in here
  NSLog(@"Im on the main thread");       
});
```

Comment: Just so the OP is clear, this is not something you'd want to do if you're already on the main thread.

Comment: What horrible thing will happen, exactly? (just for curiosity)

Comment: the main thread freezes! here is the source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7817170/644629

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662360/gcd-to-perform-task-in-main-thread (you should be able to use dispatch_async and not have a problem when on the main thread).

Comment: Would using dispatch_sync work without issue too?

Comment: yes, it would work without issues if you call `dispatch_sync` on a background thread, but you will run into a deadlock if you call `dispatch_sync` on the main thread with `dispatch_get_main_queue`

Answer (score 12):

i think this is cool, even tho in general its good form to leave the caller of a method responsible for ensuring its called on the right thread.

```
if (![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
    [self performSelector:_cmd onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:someObject waitUntilDone:NO];
    return;
}
```