# WatchKit issue retaining data between classes

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, class, watchkit, nsthread

I have two classes named `InterfaceController` and `LoadInterfaceController`.

I'm fetching information in the `LoadInterfaceController` that I wish to pass-on to a `variable` in my `InterfaceController` class.

`LoadInterfaceController`:

```
- (void)fetchData {
    NSArray *database = //fetched information
    //... on fetch complete
    InterfaceController *interfaceController = [InterfaceController alloc];
    [interfaceController initilizeDatabase:database];
}
```

`InterfaceController`:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *db;

- (void)initilizeDatabase:(NSArray *)database {
    self.db = database;

    NSLog(@"database count: %d", database.count); //: 3
    NSLog(@"db count: %d", self.db.count); //: 3

    [self utilizeInformation];
}

- (void)utilizeInformation {
    NSLog(@"db count: %d", self.db.count); //: 0
    //...
}
```

`db`'s information is not retained outside of the `initilizeDatabase:` function.

I have tried running it on the `main thread` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582223/ios-ensure-execution-on-main-thread)), but the information is still not retained. How may I specify the thread to pass-on the information from my second class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no problems with the threads or retention, everything is right from this perspective. But there is another issue: when you initialise the `InterfaceController` programmatically you create an instance of it and the `db` property is perfectly stored until your Watch loads it again, because Watch creates another instance of `InterfaceController` on its own as a result you get the empty `db` property on a new instance.

The solution I'd suggest here is to add a model entity into your architecture that will act as a singleton class and it ensures your data always will be available.

Here is an implementation considering your example:

`XYZDataBaseManager`:

```
@interface XYZDataBaseManager : NSObject

   + (nonnull XYZDataBaseManager *)sharedInstance;

   - @property (nonnull, strong) NSMutableArray *data;

@end


@implementation XYZDataBaseManager

+ (XYZDataBaseManager *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static XYZDataBaseManager *instance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        instance = [[XYZDataBaseManager alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

@end
```

`LoadInterfaceController`:

```
- (void)fetchData {
    NSArray *database = //fetched information
    [XYZDataBaseManager sharedInstance].data = database;
}
```

`InterfaceController`:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *db;

- (void)utilizeInformation {
    NSLog(@"db count: %d", [XYZDataBaseManager sharedInstance].data.count]);
}
```

Of course there are a lot of things to improve but I think the main idea is clear. And also I didn't execute this code so there might be some typos (I'm more swift-oriented).

Comment: An example would be helpful.