# WatchKit thread issue between classes

Tags: objective-c, class, watchkit, nsthread, watchos-2

I have two classes named `InterfaceController` and `LoadInterfaceController`.

I'm calling `InterfaceController`'s `uiChange` `function` from my `LoadInterfaceController`:

```
InterfaceController *interfaceController = [InterfaceController alloc];
//[interfaceController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uiChange) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:true];
[interfaceController uiChange];
```

The `function` is called, but the UI in `InterfaceController` isn't modified.

```
- (void)uiChange {
    NSLog(@"uiChange was called");
    //... make changes to the UI ...
}
```

If the `function` is called from a `function` originating from `InterfaceController` `class` the UI is changed, respectively.

I have tried calling `uiChange` on the `main thread` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582223/ios-ensure-execution-on-main-thread)), but the UI isn't responding. How may I specify the thread used for `InterfaceController`'s UI?

Comment: If you are calling UI-related APIs then they must be called on the main thread.

Comment: I already tried calling it on the main thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582223/ios-ensure-execution-on-main-thread

Comment: "try" doesn't sound like you're still doing it.  You must use the main thread and go from there.

Comment: `performSelectorOnMainThread`, `NSOperationQueue` and `dispatch_async` doesn't do the trick. `NSThread` reports it is running on the `main thread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601973/watchkit-issue-retaining-data-between-classes). Do not initialise controllers on your own, let Watch do it as a user flow happens.

I'd suggest adding into your architecture a Pub/Sub pattern. The `NSNotificationCenter` class is a good example that implements one. It allows parts of application to communicate between each other and it is used really often for controllers communication as well.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574961/using-wcsession-with-more-than-one-viewcontroller/32594447#32594447) a good example of communication between an AppDelegate and controller that I provided answering to another question recently. But if you really need I could adopt it for your example.

Comment: The issue still persist even when using `NSNotificationCenter` to communicate between classes.

Comment: @Aleksander Azizi - You should detail your task more. Why are you trying to trigger UI changes of another controller which is not showing at the moment? Use `willActivate()` method of the  `InterfaceController` class in conjunction with a singleton model from the previous question to initialise your UI before loading.

Comment: I should admit that using of `NSNotificationCenter` is more acceptable on iOS when nested `UIViewControllers' are used in other words more than one controller is displayed at the same time like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17499426/3242031

Try to use the approach from the previous comment.

Comment: After data is passed on from the `LoadInterfaceController`, the `InterfaceController`'s `WKInterfaceTable` needs to be updated. This is managed with the `uiChange` function previously mentioned.

Comment: Sorry but I got confused with your task. I feel you do something wrong but anyway I'm happy this something works for you.

Comment: You were right all along. The UI cannot be updated when initializing in a new instance.