# UILabel font takes time to update

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fonts, uilabel

```
self.name.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:17.0];
self.name.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

'**name**' is of type UILabel.
I am setting `font` and `color` of `UILabel`. I can see the `color` red as soon as I open the page (my viewcontroller). However, the font is initially of regular `size 14` and takes some to update. If I stay on the page for sometime the font gets updated automatically to its new `size 17`.

Why is there a lag in updation of the 2 properties?

Comment: You may have added static text in your storyboard file. Try removing that.

Comment: Where you write this code? (in which method). and what you set for that label in your storyboard/xib file?

Comment: @SNarula I removed static text associated with UILabel 'name' from my .xib file. Still it takes time to upadte.

Comment: @Shreyank In .xib file there is some random text and font openSans-bold with size 14. And while initializing the cell in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; I am setting the label's font and color.

Comment: Try to implement *layoutSubviews()* in UITableViewCell class. Just define `-(void)layoutSubviews()` and set the label font size inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are updating the ui elements outside main thread.

All ui elements should be updated in main thread. Not doing it could lead to inconsistent ui, delayed update and sometimes crashes as well.

If you are not in main thread and want to update ui elements. Check 2nd and 3rd answer(which is not accepted) in [iOS - Ensure execution on main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582223/ios-ensure-execution-on-main-thread) to know that.

Comment: Put my comment inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}); and worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Actually replaced it with [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {

   //Your code goes in here
   NSLog(@"Main Thread Code");

}]; because apparently, there are some issues related with the previous approach as documented in the stack overflow post

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with calling `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` even if you are already on the main queue.

Comment: I have not added the way of running code in main thread because it was already answered well in another link, so just included link!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the font file exists and that the font name is same as @"OpenSans" , capitals also.

It may be because of name mismatch of font

You may check all the fonts in app by :

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
NSArray *fontNames;
NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
{
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
    fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                 [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                  [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
    for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
    {
        NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
    }
}
```